# Who are all the characters you can unlock for trial maps in FE6?

Tags: fire-emblem-binding-blade

after beating FE6 for the first time (true ending, normal mode) I noticed that there was an option for trial maps. I had heard of these being unlocked after beating the game, but because of the emulator I used to use, it would mess with the save file, never really saving the game properly, so I had to rely solely on save states after loading one. Anyways, upon starting one up, I noticed a new character in my roster: Narcian! I knew there were certain characters and maps you unlock by fulfilling certain requirements (beat hard mode 3 times, etc.), and so my question is, **Who are all the special characters you can unlock for use in trial maps, and how do you unlock them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a total of 8 characters you can unlock for trail maps. The requirements to unlock is relative to how many times you clear the story<sup>1</sup> regardless of difficulty.

1. Narshen - Clear the game **once**
2. Gale - Clear the game **twice**
3. Hector   - Clear the game **three** times
4. Brunya   - Clear the game **four** times
5. Eliwood  - Clear the game **five** times
6. Murdoch  - Clear the game **six** times
7. Zephiel  - Clear the game **seven** times
8. Guinevere    - Clear the game **nine** times

In addition to the extra characters, there a total of 5 Trials Maps that can be played. The requirements to unlock is relative to how you clear the story.

1. Critical Valley - Clear the game at least once
2. Island of Heavy Rain - Clear the game at least once
3. Defense Line in the Snow - Clear the game with the "Final Chapter" ending
4. Pirates’ Challenge - Clear the game on hard mode
5. Roy's Test - Clear the game on hard mode with the "Final Chapter" ending

**Sources**

- [Character Recruitment](https://serenesforest.net/binding-blade/characters/recruitment/#TrialMapCharacters)
- [Trial Maps](https://serenesforest.net/binding-blade/miscellaneous/trial-maps/)

---

<sup>1</sup> The game must be cleared start to finished every time. Simply beating the story multiple times on a single save will not count towards the numbers cleared.

Comment: what about hard mode? does that do anything? and what about the other trial maps?

Comment: @BlazingTrio In addition to SerenesForest, two other sources did not specify difficultly when clearing the game - so it's safe to assume the characters can be unlocked in any difficulty. I did miss the part asking about trial maps, so I added that part